# how would i write scores 1&2 to a text file in python?

Tags: python

I'm making a game where two players roll 2 dice each and receive points depending on the number they roll. There will be 5 rounds in a game. Whoever has the highest total of points by the end wins.

At the end I would like it to write the winner's name and score to a text file.

How would I go about doing that?

Many thanks,
   Roshan

```
#Import required functions
import time
import random

#Created required variables
goes=0
score1=0
score2=0
password1="2w$&Kk"
password2="Zc7g/m"

#Authorisation
passcheck1=input("PLayer 1, please enter the set password for your player: ")
passcheck2=input("PLayer 2, please enter the set password for your player: ")
if password1 == passcheck1:
    player1=input("Player 1, please enter your name: ")
else:
    exit()
if password2 == passcheck2:
    player2=input("Player 2, please enter your name: ")
else:
    exit()

#Game
while goes <10:
    print(player1, "rolls 2 dice")
    time.sleep(2)
    dice1=random.randint(0,6)
    dice2=random.randint(0,6)
    dice3=random.randint(0,6)
    total=dice1+dice2

    if dice1 == dice2:
        print(player1, "rolled a double! They are now allowed to roll a third die. The number on the third die is the amount of points they earn")
        score1=score1+dice3

    elif (total % 2) == 0:
        score1=score1+10
        goes=goes+1

    else:
        score1=score1-5
        goes=goes+1

    print (score1)
    if score1 < 0:
        print(player1,"'s score has reached below 0, therefore has lost.")
        goes=10


    time.sleep(2)


    print(player2, "rolls 2 dice")
    time.sleep(2)
    dice1=random.randint(0,6)
    dice2=random.randint(0,6)
    dice3=random.randint(0,6)
    total=dice1+dice2

    if dice1 == dice2:
        print(player2, "rolled a double! They are now allowed to roll a third die. The number on the third die is the amount of points they earn")
        score2=score2+dice3

    elif (total % 2) == 0:
        score2=score2+10
        goes=goes+1

    else:
        score2=score2-5
        goes=goes+1

    print(score2)
    if score2 < 0:
        print(player2,"'s score has reached below 0, therefore has lost.")
        goes=10

#Deciding who wins
if goes==10:
    if score1 == score2:
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Both players scores are the same and must roll another five times to see who wins")
        goes=0
    elif score1 < score2:
        print("Player 2 wins")
        f = open("scores.txt", "a")
        f.write(player2)
        f.write(score2)
        f.close
    else:
        print("Player 1 wins")
        f = open("scores.txt", "a")
        f.write(player1)
        f.write(score1)
        f.close
```

Comment: what's the exact problem?

Comment: `open()`, `write()`, `close()` - and don't forget to add `'\n'`

Comment: `f.write( "{},{}\n".format(player2,score2) )` ?

Comment: im unable to write either scores to a file as they are numbers

Comment: don't you know how to convert number to string ?! `str(123)`

Comment: @furas `with` would be better imo

Comment: @Nathan it is small detail - but it seems OP may not know `with` so you could create answer to show how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
with open('my_file.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(f"{player2},{score2}\n")
```

or if you're not using python 3.6 or later

```
    f.write( "{},{}\n".format(player2,score2) )
```

The way it works is that you open a file `f`, with argument `a` (append) to indicate you wish to add it to the existing lines. Because you use a `with` statement to open the file, it automatically closes the file and you won't have to worry about the file not being closed and eating up memory.

If you want to overwrite the file, you should use `w` instead of `a`.